# How to resolve sharepoint error- 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: sharepoint, mule

Hi I'm querying on sharepoint, below is the query and connection details.

```
   <sharepoint:online-connection-config name="Microsoft_SharePoint_2013__Online_Connection" username="${Sharepoint.Username}" password="${Sharepoint.Password}" siteUrl="${Sharepoint.SiteUrl}" disableCnCheck="true" doc:name="Microsoft SharePoint 2013: Online Connection">
        <reconnect frequency="10000" count="5"/>
    </sharepoint:online-connection-config>

    <sharepoint:file-query config-ref="Microsoft_SharePoint_2013__Online_Connection" query="dsql:SELECT Author,CheckInComment,CheckOutType,CheckedOutByUser,ContentTag,CustomizedPageStatus,ETag,Exists,Length,Level,LinkingUrl,ListItemAllFields,LockedByUser,MajorVersion,MinorVersion,ModifiedBy,Name,ServerRelativeUrl,TimeCreated,TimeLastModified,Title,UIVersion,UIVersionLabel,UniqueId,Versions FROM 'Sell sheetsBrochures' ORDER BY TimeLastModified DESC LIMIT ${sharepoint.file.fetch.number}" doc:name="Modified File query "/>
```

It is throwing below error while querying the sharepoint.

```
    ********************************************************************************
    Message               : Failed to invoke fileQuery. Message payload is of type: String
    Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
    Code                  : MULE_ERROR-29999
    JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
    Payload               : 
    ********************************************************************************
    Exception stack is:
    1. 500 Internal Server Error (org.springframework.web.4.1.6.RELEASE.shaded.client.HttpServerErrorException)
      org.springframework.web.4.1.6.RELEASE.shaded.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler:94 (null)
    2. Code: 500 Message: {"error":{"code":"-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"User cannot be found."}}} (org.mule.module.sharepoint.exception.SharepointException)
      org.mule.module.sharepoint.rest.AbstractSharepointClientImpl:148 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/module/sharepoint/exception/SharepointException.html)
    3. Failed to invoke fileQuery. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
      org.mule.devkit.processor.DevkitBasedMessageProcessor:133 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)

********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
org.springframework.web.4.1.6.RELEASE.shaded.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.springframework.web.4.1.6.RELEASE.shaded.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.4.1.6.RELEASE.shaded.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:614)
    at org.springframework.web.4.1.6.RELEASE.shaded.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:570)
    at org.springframework.web.4.1.6.RELEASE.shaded.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:545)
    at org.springframework.web.4.1.6.RELEASE.shaded.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:466)
    at org.mule.module.sharepoint.rest.AbstractSharepointClientImpl.exchangeForObject(AbstractSharepointClientImpl.java:144)
```

Comment: where are you adding this query? Can you add piece of your code too?

Comment: updated the question, while querying the sharepoint getting the error

Answer (score 1):

You have a `500 Internal Server Error`, meaning something went wrong on the server you are querying. The error message is `User cannot be found.`, the user you configured on your `Microsoft_SharePoint_2013__Online_Connection` configuration probably doesn't exists anymore on your SharePoint server, or have some configuration issue.

EDIT: with the details you gave, it seems the user you have configured is causing some bug on the server side. If you have access to the server you should check the logs and ensure this user is properly configured and accessible.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer. Hope this helps, however with only the client side showing a server issue there's not much to do but go and check what happened on the server ;)