# MS SharePoint HTTP REST API getFileByID(): 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: api, sharepoint, office365, http-status-code-500

I'm seeing sporadic (periodic) 500 responses for SharePoint API requests that I cannot explain.  The problem endpoint is in the form:

```
https://<mytenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<mysite>/_api/web/getFileByID('a8fda9ec-016f-41e6-9c3e-6aacbe57797e')?$select=Author/Title,Author/LoginName,Author/Email,Author/AadObjectId/NameId,UniqueId,Name,Length,ServerRelativeUrl,TimeLastModified,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/PrincipalType,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Title,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/LoginName,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Email,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/AadObjectId/NameId,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users/PrincipalType,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users/Title,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users/LoginName,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users/Email,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users/AadObjectId/NameId&$expand=Author/AadObjectId,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/RoleDefinitionBindings,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/AadObjectId,ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users/AadObjectId
```

Query parameters in a readable form:

```
$select=
    Author/Title,
    Author/LoginName,
    Author/Email,
    Author/AadObjectId/NameId,
    UniqueId,
    Name,
    Length,
    ServerRelativeUrl,
    TimeLastModified,
    ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/PrincipalType,
    ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Title,
    ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/LoginName,
    ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Email,
    ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/AadObjectId/NameId,
    ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users/PrincipalType,
    ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users/Title,
    ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users/LoginName,
    ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users/Email,
    ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users/AadObjectId/NameId

$expand=
    Author/AadObjectId,
    ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/RoleDefinitionBindings,
    ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/AadObjectId,
    ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users/AadObjectId
```

Normally I get a 200 response as expected, with no problem.

When for some files I get a 500 response, the body is the following:

```
{"error":{"code":"-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"User cannot be found."}}}
```

However, If I remove the "Author/AadObjectId" from the `$expand` list, the request succeeds. Such problems come from both SharePoint sites and OneDrive personal sites. The problem seems to be persistent for the given SharePoint file.

There is a similar case reported on the StackOverflow: [How to resolve sharepoint error- 500 Internal Server Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882485/how-to-resolve-sharepoint-error-500-internal-server-error). This was the same error response, and the suggestion was that the problem might be either with the resource or with the user.

However, in my case, I can see that the actual file Author is a valid and active user, and the file in question is valid and accessible otherwise.

So my only explanation would be a problem with data integrity of some sort on the Microsoft side.

My question is if it's a known issue, and how I can fix my API call.

Comment: Did you got any solution for the above question?